# How to use Mongo Aggregation to limit results around a given input?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I looked through the [pipeline stages docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), but did not see how to do this.

Suppose you have a user, and each user has points.

```
User    Points
 A        22
 B        11
 C        15
 D         7
```

So, we use `'$sort': { points: -1 }` to order the users by points.

Is it possible to use a Mongo Aggregation Stage to find the users before and after a given user?

So, given user C (by id), it would return `[A, C, B]`.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. Maybe exists any better solution.

**Disclaimer**: I assume the user points is unique

We can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get expected result, but at **high** cost (very large query)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "givenUser": [
        {
          $match: {
            "user": "C"
          }
        }
      ],
      "allUser": [
        {
          $sort: {
            "Points": -1
          }
        }
      ],
      "orderedPoints": [
        {
          $sort: {
            "Points": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            Points: {
              $push: "$Points"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$Points"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      allUser: 1,
      currIndex: {
        $indexOfArray: [
          "$orderedPoints.Points",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$givenUser.Points",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      beforeIndex: {
        $add: [
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$orderedPoints.Points",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$givenUser.Points",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          -1
        ]
      },
      afterIndex: {
        $add: [
          {
            $indexOfArray: [
              "$orderedPoints.Points",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$givenUser.Points",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: [
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$allUser",
            {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $lt: [
                    "$beforeIndex",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                then: 999,
                else: "$beforeIndex"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$allUser",
            "$currIndex"
          ]
        },
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$allUser",
            "$afterIndex"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

---

```
[
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "Points": 22,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "user": "A"
      },
      {
        "Points": 15,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "user": "C"
      },
      {
        "Points": 11,
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "user": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wAOS1Ef2jAV)

Steps:

1. We keep into separate fields:

   - Given user (C),
   - Order all users by points
   - Order all points and store inside array (I wish MongoDB allows find array index by object too)
2. Now we find given user index, calculate indexes for "before"/"after" players.
3. Now, we create result with 3 elements (before, current, after).

**Note:** If given user is first / last, we ensure to return `null` for before / after items.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it possible to inject an index ID (via $project?) and then limit based on it? So, after sorting, the elements would have index_id: 1, index_id: 2, etc.

Comment: I've tried, but no luck. Only `$unwind` can say us array idx. [includearrayindex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex). But if know User `C` points, you may calculate exact idx (`db.collection.count({Points:{$gt:15}})`) and then use this: [https://mongoplayground.net/p/yfroFE2U7Cl](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yfroFE2U7Cl)